# Have a C program do nothing while it waits for a GPIO input on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I have a program that polls a weight indicator using the modbus protocol and writes the read data in a database, however, I need to be able to have the program run all the time without doing anything until the Raspberry Pi receives a GPIO input. Once the pin goes high, it'll run the polling function and go back to waiting for another trigger.

I'm not a programmer, so I would like to know the best way to have the program wait for the GPIO input.

Comment: [Interrupts](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/gpio/README.md) is a way to go.  Or do you have a specific requirement to keep polling?

Comment: @vk_gst my only requirement to start polling is a button push that will set the pin to high. After that, I need to go back to waiting for another button push.

Comment: Try configuring the interrupts for the GPIO pin you want, and on interrupt/button press  invoke a callback function(interrupt handler) that reads the weight indicator values and on second button press stops reading the weight indicator. This is one way of approaching. Here is a [demo](https://medium.com/@rxseger/interrupt-driven-i-o-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-leds-and-pushbuttons-rising-falling-edge-detection-36c14e640fef)

Comment: It is Unix and RPi. So just wait for the gpio in the loop. If not active go sleep for some time 50-200ms

Comment: @vk_gst Actually, I wouldn't need that second button because it's only a single reading per button press, I'll look into interrupts, thanks!

Comment: @P__J__ Could this be achieved with a while loop? Something like while(pin==LOW){sleep(50us)}?

Comment: sitting in a `while()` loop means the program will be doing nothing useful, most of the time..  It that what you want?

Comment: @user3629249 I just need it to wait for the GPIO pin to go high and then run a function. So, it's not going to be doing anything useful most of the time.